# Count(*) of grouped values in row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a few thousand rows for our customers and the services they have, in short looking like this

[image]

Service1, 2 and 3 are the services clients have (every customer can only have one but this isn't relevant at the moment).
So, what I need is to present a select statement that has 4 columns, distinct state, and then count(*) for every service in that particular state. Like this

[image]

So in Arizona, we have 2 clients paying for service1, 4 others with service2 and 3 with service3, and so on.

I've tried doing sub-queries in the select statement but I can't find to get around it. I thought about using a cursor but I guess there should be an easier way. If you can point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) operator

Comment: As advised when asking the question, please do not use images for data. Use tabular markdown.

Comment: `count` paired with `case when` can also be used and its much more portable (can be used in another dbms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivoting for a static number of columns can be done as:

```sql
select
  state,
  count(case when service = 'service1' then 1 end) as s1,
  count(case when service = 'service2' then 1 end) as s2,
  count(case when service = 'service3' then 1 end) as s3  
from t
group by state
```